# Use wordpress only for admin and permanent data while nodejs for all the front end logic

Tags: javascript, node.js, wordpress, web-services, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to build an application stack with a mix of nodejs and WordPress, something just like wordpress.com is doing recently but how to exactly achieve it.
So let's say I already have a website with some persistent data such as name, info password etc which is handled by WordPress while some data such as GPS location daily activity log (rapidly changing data) etc are handled by nodejs.

Is it possible to achieve this by running WordPress and nodejs on a different port and combine them using Rest API or is there any better approach for this type of Stack.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Could-I-use-Wordpress-as-a-backend here is a very fleshed out example using React: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-build-react-apps-on-top-of-the-wordpress-rest-api-bcc632808025

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak thank you! very helpful